# sp::over() for point in polygon analysis

Tags: r, gis, polygon, shapefile

I have a shapefile named "ind_adm" and a SpatialPointsDataFrame called "pnts". The "pnts" contains points generated at random, and some of the points overlap with the polygon. See picture below.
[image]

Now, I want do do a point in polygon analysis, i.e. I want to find out which points lie inside the gray polygon representing the boundary of India. For this I am using the over() function in the sp library.

```
pt.in.poly <- sp::over(ind_adm, pnts, fn = mean) #do the join
```

However, the output I am getting is

```
    >pt.in.poly
    values
    0 6.019467
```

I should actually get the index of the points that are "in" the polygon.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should not supply a function. You are aggregating the attribute values of your points over the geometry of the polygon, (i.e. the number returned is the `mean` of the attribute of the points that fall within the polygon). In addition you have your `x` and `y` the wrong way round for what you want to do. Should be...

```
over( pnts , ind_adm , fn = NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks Simon. The problem was with the order of x and y. The function specifies how the objects are aggregated, hence "mean" works fine. I guess a good way to remember the order of x and y in the future is by remembering that the analysis is called "Point in Polygon", hence the point goes first, followed by the polygon.

Answer (score 30):

Found this concise and intuitive syntax for over:

```
   pnts[ind_adm,]
```

from [this](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/intro-spatial-rl.pdf) Intro document

Comment: This answer worked best for me. In my case pnts was a SpatialPointsDataFrame and ind_adm  a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

Comment: Thank you so much! This deserves 1000 upvotes, very intuitive and works perfectly for subsetting location data by shapefiles, especially when working with census data and revenue and so forth

Comment: Great solution. Tip: make sure that pnts and ind_adm use the same CRS.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `point.in.poly` fom `spatialEco` package. It "intersects point and polygon feature classes and adds polygon attributes to points".

```
library(spatialEco)

new_shape <- point.in.poly(pnts, ind_adm)
```

Comment: You have to make sure that your spatialpolygon (in this case ind_adm) does not have missing values in some of the columns, otherwise it will show an error when you use point.in.poly.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use the `st_intersection` function from the `sf` package:

#### **Load the library**

`library(sf)`

#### **Create a simple feature geometry (polygon) from your polygon**

`ind_adm <- st_as_sf(ind_adm)`

#### **Create a simple feature geometry (point) from your points of interest**

(24047 is the EPSG code for India)

`pnts <- st_as_sf(pnts) %>% st_set_crs(., 24047)`

#### **Keep only the points inside the polygon**

`kept_points <- st_intersection(ind_adm, pnts)`