# Keep getting NAs when I run Over() function on Points(Lat,Lon) on shapefile polygons

Tags: r, shapefile, r-sf, r-sp, rgdal

I am not sure why i am keep getting NA whenever I run the `Over` function with Latitude and Longitude point on the polygon from shapefile. Please note that this is first time for me doing the spatial analysis, but I have done my research and replicated things, but didn't succeed. I need some points which are outside of the polygon to be NA, so I can focus on the real data.

I read these sources since these pertain to my cause but I can't work my problem out:
[sp::over() for point in polygon analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002744/spover-for-point-in-polygon-analysis)
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133625/checking-if-points-fall-within-polygon-shapefile
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278723/r-error-in-checking-point-inside-polygon

Here is my code chunk

```r
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(readr)

gainsville_df <- read_csv("311_Service_Requests__myGNV_.csv")
gnv <- readOGR("~\\Downloads\\GIS_cgbound", layer = "cgbound")

gnv_latlon <- spTransform(gnv, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84"))

gnv_raw <- data.frame(Longitude= gainsville_df$Longitude, Latitude= gainsville_df$Latitude)

coordinates(gnv_raw) <- ~Longitude + Latitude
proj4string(gnv_raw) <- proj4string(gnv)
over(gnv_raw, as(gnv,"SpatialLinesDataFrame"))

#Yeilds:
#  FID_cgboun Id Perimeter Area Acres Hectares Shape_Leng
#1         NA NA        NA   NA    NA       NA         NA

# Desired Output:
# Whereas I should have seen which gainesville Latitudes and Longitude are within the shpaefile
# polygon so I can drop the outliers, that have the NA. According to this, none of my LatLon points 
# are inside the polygon.
```

The datafiles are here:
Shapefile: https://github.com/THsTestingGround/SO_readOGR_quest/tree/master/GIS_cgbound
reading csv file: https://github.com/THsTestingGround/SO_readOGR_quest/blob/master/311_Service_Requests__myGNV_.csv

I would appreciate if someone can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that your point data is an sf object since you have `POINT (-82.34323174 29.67058748)` as character. Hence, I reconstructed your data first. I assigned a projection here as well.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(RCurl)

url <- getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/THsTestingGround/SO_readOGR_quest/master/311_Service_Requests__myGNV_.csv")

mydf <- read_csv(url) %>% 
        mutate(Location = gsub(x = Location, pattern = "POINT \\(|\\)", replacement = "")) %>% 
        separate(col = "Location", into = c("lon", "lat"), sep = " ") %>% 
        st_as_sf(coords = c(3,4)) %>% 
        st_set_crs(4326)
```

I imported your shapefile using `sf` package since your data (`mydf` in this demonstration) is an sf object. When I imported the data, I realized that I had `LINESTRING`, not polygons. I believe this is the reason why `over()` did not work. Here I created polygons. Specifically, I joined all seven polygons all together.

```
mypoly <- st_read("cgbound.shp") %>% 
          st_transform(crs = 4326) %>% 
          st_polygonize() %>% 
          st_union()
```

Let's check how your data points and polygon are like. You surely have data points staying outside of the polygon.

```
ggplot() +
geom_sf(data = mypoly) +
geom_point(data = mydf, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude))
```

[image]

You said, "I need some points which are outside of the polygon to be NA." So I decided to create a new column in `mydf` using `st_intersects()`. If a data point stays in the polygon, you see TRUE in the new column, `check`. Otherwise, you see FALSE.

```
mutate(mydf,
      check = as.vector(st_intersects(x = mydf, y = mypoly, sparse = FALSE))) -> result
```

Finally, check how data points are checked.

```
ggplot() +
geom_sf(data = mypoly) +
geom_point(data = result, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, color = check))
```

[image]

If you wanna use `over()` mixing with this sf way, you can do the following.

```
mutate(mydf,
       check = over(as(mydf, "Spatial"), as(mypoly, "Spatial")))
```

The last thing you wanna do is to subset the data

```
filter(result, check == TRUE)
```

**THE SIMPLEST WAY**

I demonstrated you how things are working with this sf approach. But the following is actually all you need. `st_filter()` extracts data points staying in `mypoly`. In this case, data points staying outside are removed. If you do not have to create NAs for these points, this is much easier.

```
st_filter(x = mydf, y = mypoly, predicate = st_intersects) -> result2

ggplot() +
geom_sf(data = mypoly) +
geom_sf(data = result2)
```

[image]

Comment: @AgentSmith You are welcome. It is up to you if you wanna use sp or sf package in the end. But sf package makes your life a lot easier in my view.

Comment: Sorry, I as following several examples over the web since first time for me doing this type of stuff. But I will keep in mind for sure, in fact, I would go on YouTube now, and see some `sf` tutorial.

Comment: @AgentSmith Good luck. I myself have more things to learn. :)